# Spread Operator equivalent in IE - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function to populate dropdowns for individual table rows like:

```
$scope.possibleOptions = getUniqueValues($scope.yypeOptions, 'yypeOption')
    .map(function(id) {
            return {
                id: id,
                name: id
            });

function getUniqueValues(array, prop) {
    return [...new Set(array.map(item => item[prop]))];
}
```

where, `$scope.yypeOptions` is:

```
$scope.yypeOptions = [{
    yypeOption: "option1"
}, {
    yypeOption: "option2"
}];
```

I now have to make it compatible to IE. The `spread` and `=>` operator is something I have to replace.

Went through [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) link. But I could not get any understanding how to replace the Set inside an Array feature.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill)...

Comment: Are you sure that your IE version supports `...` (spread) operator?

Comment: @KoshVery I was just about to edit my comment regarding this syntax, not to mention the support for [`Set`](https://caniuse.com/#search=set)...

Comment: $injector is an Angular thing, right?  Does this need an Angular tag?

Comment: And `Set`--we can't just say "IE", we need to specify the version (and whether you actually mean IE or Edge, because some people think Edge is IE).

Comment: [IE11 does not support spread.](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-spread_(...)_operator)  Go through your code and ensure that the features you are using are supported by the browser you are targeting.  Use a linter to expedite the process.

Comment: ....or just use a browser

Comment: Thank you for your response guys :) I use IE 11

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a simple way that could work on IE

```js
data =[{name:"a"}, {name:"a"},{name:"x"}]

function getUniqueValues(array, prop) {
    return array.map(function(item) { return item[prop]; })
    .filter(function (item, index, self){ return self.indexOf(item) === index; }); // distinct
}

console.log(getUniqueValues(data, "name"))
```

Answer (score 3):

The getUniqueValues there is performing two things for you; removing duplicated elements and also cloning the array. However, the map already is a clone of the array, so you just need to remove duplicates; you could use something like this:

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

function getUniqueValues(array, prop) {
    function mapper(item) {
        return item[prop];
    }
    return array.map(mapper).filter(onlyUnique);
}
```

I'd suggest you to take a look at stuff like webpack and babel in order to use the latest JS and also work on IE, by using transpiler and polyfills to generate compatible code ;)

PS. I don't have IE right now to test if filter works, but I'm pretty sure it does; otherwise you could remove duplicates by hand with a plain old for.

Comment: Map dose not do a deep clone. but in his case hes returning a property, if the property is an object then its not deep cloned :)

Comment: @Alen.Toma nor does the Set, so, regardless, the behavior is the same! :)

Answer (score 3):

Your two syntaxes that you are asking about are the fat arrow for [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). You can replace the former with a standard function expression and the latter with iteration using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach) that adds the elements to an array. In addition, you also need a replacement for the `Set` constructor that initializes it from an iterable. Instead, you need to add the elements one by one.

You can write your function like this. This first adds all values into a set, and then gets the values from the list and back to a new array:

```
function getUniqueValues(array, prop) {
    // create set
    var set = new Set();
    array.forEach(function (item) {
        set.add(item[prop]);
    });

    // convert set to array
    var result = [];
    set.forEach(function (item) {
        result.push(item);
    });
    return result;
}
```

Since there is basic support for [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), including `forEach`, in Internet Explorer 11, you can use this without a polyfill.

Here is an example that runs fine in Internet Explorer 11:

```js
var options = [
    { yypeOption: "option1" },
    { yypeOption: "option2" },
    { yypeOption: "option1" },
    { yypeOption: "option1" },
    { yypeOption: "option3" },
];

function getUniqueValues(array, prop) {
    var set = new Set();
    array.forEach(function (item) {
        set.add(item[prop]);
    });
    var result = [];
    set.forEach(function (item) {
        result.push(item);
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(getUniqueValues(options, 'yypeOption'));
```

Comment: Hi Poke. The IE throws `TypeError: Unable to get property 'map' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: Hi Poke. Thanks a lot. But I have to go with @Alen, considering 1. Simplest solution code. 2.Testing and answering without edits.

Comment: This seems to be fair. Sure Poke :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting IE11, since it does not support ES6 features like "=>", you have 2 options:

1) include a polyfill like babeljs so that the ES6 code works in IE11

- I have not done this previously but I read that this is what polyfills do

OR

2) replace your ES6 code with equivalent ES5 code

- https://babeljs.io/repl - here you can get ES5 equivalent of your ES6 code.

Answer (score 1):

I think The problem is not related with 'map',
actually you should not use spread operator (...) in IE11.
you may check it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Hi Emrah, yes got it. Even the => seems to be not supported in IE11. Any help on how can I resolve this?